# issues with notify_url in paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am a developer and we have paypal payment sytem integrated with our shop since long.
We have implemented the notify_url paramter in checkout code and was working fine since 4 months back. But now we could see that when a payment is done, we are not notified via the notify_url we specified. But however if we check the url via the IPN simulator, we can see everythign works as expected, but not not notifying automatically when payment is done .

What could be the issue or what all do we need to cross check for this issue to be solved

Answer (score 0):

Did you received any 'PayPal Instant Payment Notification Warning' email from PayPal? This email could be telling you that there's an issue with your IPN URL when PayPal trying to post back the notification to your server, and that could be the reason you didn't receive the notification message from PayPal.

Otherwise, I would recommend you to contact PayPal technical support via https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask and providing the detail of your PayPal account for them to troubleshoot on this issue.